# STATIC_DIRS in django

Tags: django, django-templates

Having a bit of a problem here in my settings.py file in django my templates cannot see my css and image files

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/assets/'

STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'static/')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('assets', os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'static/')),

)
```

but each time i use this;

```
STATIC_URL = '/assets/'

STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'static/')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('assets', os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'static/'),)

)
```

it works but my uploaded files refuse to show in html pages

N.B notice the comma i change at the end of the static files declaration.

Comment: Use [Media_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#media-root) for uploaded files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During [development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development), you can serve user-uploaded media files from [MEDIA_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root) using MEDIA_URL.